# Golang get process time to an action

Tags: go

I really interested in how much time is spending time to do this action. Does anybody have any best idea? or any library. I did with simple way, but it seems as wrong way. Because I did have more experience with workin on `go`

My have that code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var d int = 0
    var beginTime = time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {

        for c := 0; c < 100; c++ {
            d = 1
        }
    }
    var endTime = time.Now()
    fmt.Println(beginTime, endTime)
    fmt.Println(time.Since(beginTime))
    fmt.Println(d)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [built-in Benchmarks](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks).

> A sample benchmark function looks like this:
>
> ```
> func BenchmarkHello(b *testing.B) {
>     for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
>         fmt.Sprintf("hello")
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The benchmark function must run the target code b.N times. During benchark execution, b.N is adjusted until the benchmark function lasts long enough to be timed reliably. The output
>
> ```
> BenchmarkHello    10000000    282 ns/op
> ```
>
> means that the loop ran 10000000 times at a speed of 282 ns per loop.

**EDIT:** If you want to measure time of doing something at runtime, and not in your tests, your way looks fine to me.